# HTML element-specific values in Javascript (in IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I want to be able to basically set custom attributes on an HTML element (preferably using jQuery). i.e.

`$("#element").attr('myVar','10px');`

And this works perfectly in browsers such as Chrome and Firefox. However, apparently not even IE 8 supports custom attributes, unfortunately. How can I do something similar that is IE-compatible?

I've tried just attempting to set the value such as

`obj.myValue = "10px";`

But when I attempted to retrieve the value later in the script, it was undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set custom attributes directly on the element. Why? Because there are reserved properties and it's messy and buggy and conflicts will arise. Instead, use jQuery's `.data` which internally stores custom properties/keys per DOM objects.

```
$('#element').data('key', 'value');
```

Get the value by just specifying `$('#element').data('key')`.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for. ...Although it doesn't appear to solve the problem. DANG IT!

Comment: after setting the value, try inspecting the element (using IE developer tool bar) and make sure that value is set on the element

Comment: 1. Make sure you reference the right value 2. Make sure you do mathematical operations properly in regards to `px` and unit-less values.

Comment: NEVERMIND, just did a little variable snooping and realized that .css("height") was returning "auto" instead of the px value, so I used .outerHeight instead.

Comment: You need to simplify the problem. Right now you're doing too much assumption. `        var rot = $(this).parent().find("div");` - shouldn't this be just `$(this).closest('div')` ? Did you confirm that the `.data` value is even set? Did you confirm `.css('height')` returns a value?

Comment: You know me too well, meder. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `data` method. [apidocs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) here.

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to
>   attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from
>   circular references and therefore free
>   from memory leaks